# Show this property of primitive quadratic forms

Tags: quadratic-forms, discriminant, modular-group

> Let $f(x,y),g(x,y)$ be two primitive quadratic forms of discriminant $D < 0$. Then the following statements are equivalent:
>
> (i) $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are in the same genus i.e. they represent the same values in $(\Bbb Z/D \Bbb Z)^*$.
>
> (ii) $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are equivalent modulo $m$ for all nonzero integers $m$.

$(ii) \implies (i)$ is trivial, however I cannot do the other part. A hint given in this problem is to use the complete character of the genera. I cannot make any progress. Please help.

Comment: This is just an idea: if $f$ and $g$ represent the same number $a$ then $f\sim aX^2+f'$ and $g\sim aX^2+g'$ and then you can proceed by induction. I am more familiar with rational quadratic forms, I don't know if I'm missing some subtlety of integral forms.